# setNavigationBarHidden doesn't work after setViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I found that `setNavigationBarHidden` doesn't work after `setViewControllers`?

This is my code:

- `HomeNavController.swift`:

  ```
  class HomeNavController: UINavigationController {

      weak var tabBar: HomeTabBar!

      var tab: HomeTab = .match {
          didSet {
              switch self.tab {
              case .match:
                  self.setViewControllers([MatchViewController()], animated: false)
              case .moments:
                  self.setViewControllers([MomentsViewController()], animated: false)
              case .myPosts:
                  self.setViewControllers([PostsViewController()], animated: false)
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `MatchViewController.swift`

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
  }
  ```

It works well when I first switch to `MatchViewController` instance, but it doesn't works after I change the `HomeNavController` instance's viewControllers with func `setViewControllers`.

Is it a bug of `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Tried on ViewDidAppear?

Comment: Are you also setting the navigationController to hidden in your Moments & Posts ViewControllers?

Comment: Yes I had trying on ViewDidAppear, setting hidden in my Moments & Posts ViewControllers, but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try setting the properties, this worked in my case:

```
    let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    let transparentColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0);
    // Sets the translucent background color
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = transparentColor
    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:transparentColor]
    // Hides the border
    navigationBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationBarAppearance.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea, I will try it tomarrow, thank you. And I still want to know if I do something wrong cause it doesn't work...

Comment: Finally I found this is my fault, I have a custom navbar... And I think your answer is useful in some cases.